# else not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

here is my code

```
  $('#login').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var vars = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
    var url = "singInDrProcess.php";
    ajax.open("POST", url, true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(vars);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            var return_data = ajax.responseText;
            if(return_data!="success_login")
                document.getElementById("result_signin").innerHTML = return_data;
            }else{
                window.location.replace("profile.php");
                           }
        }
  });
```

The problem is , when user comes to this page and tries to Login, even if he never enters any username or password, and just clicks on my login button, page will be redirected to profile.php
I mean, the ELSE part always runs, either there is data on fields or all of them are empty
what is the problem?

Comment: what a shame:(
thank u but still not working
after clicking on lonig, it goes directly to "singInDrProcess.php"
instead of "profile.php", and ofcourse with a "Object not found " error, but both profile.php and signInDrprocess.php are in my folders and working 
???

Comment: give try with adding full url of your page in `replace` function like `window.location.replace("http://example.com/profile.php);`

Answer (score 2):

Indent your code according to your parenthesis:

```
if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
    var return_data = ajax.responseText;
    if(return_data!="success_login")
        document.getElementById("result_signin").innerHTML = return_data;
}else{
     window.location.replace("profile.php");
}
} // extraneous
```

That's not what you want.

Adding a `{` after `if(return_data!="success_login")` or removing the `}` before `else`will fix it:

```
if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
    var return_data = ajax.responseText;
    if (return_data!="success_login") {
        document.getElementById("result_signin").innerHTML = return_data;
    } else {
        window.location.replace("profile.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `{` after `if(return_data!="success_login")`

but should be

```
 if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
 //--------------add opening curly brace here---^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(return_data!="success_login")
            document.getElementById("result_signin").innerHTML = return_data;
        }else{
            window.location.replace("profile.php");
                       }
    }
});
```

should be changed to

```
if(return_data!="success_login")
            {document.getElementById("result_signin").innerHTML = return_data;
        }else{
            window.location.replace("profile.php");
                       }
    }
});
```

You forgot the { after the if parentheses.

Also, you should use JSHint, as it helps with errors and such.